# Mat-datepicker - How to show user saved value in input field - [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngmodel

i don't know what am exactly missing. but not able to find the way to fix the issue.

I have Mat-datepicker - user selects date and saves it. dates are saved successfully. but when going back to see the changes. date is not there.

clearly, i want to show user saved date in mat-datepicker.

```
<div class="end-date">              
                <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="myDatepicker"  name="appEndDate" [value] = "appEndDate" [(ngModel)]="appEndDate">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="myDatepicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #myDatepicker></mat-datepicker>
                  </mat-form-field>
          </div>
```

in ts.

```
 appEndDate: string;

    ngOninit(){
    this.appEndDate = this.someService['appoinementDetails'].endDate;

}
```

i dont understand from official doc, about get value method.

**solution : sometimes(...rarely )clearing browser cache might help you.
in my scenario. newly saved values not getting updated on model and it has showed some unwanted junk values which i used to save in some other form fields.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xjfnhk

you just need to bind it with or `[(ngModel)]`, value or formcontrol.

In your case, the date isn't probably showing because it's in wrong format. you could put

```
appEndDate = new Date(this.someService['appoinementDetails'].endDate);
```

I got the code from [here](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples).

Comment: i dont know why your solution is not working me. in app. it binding only current date. whenever i change the date and save it. it saving successfully

Comment: I couldn't understand what's not working correctly? check the red formfield. I updated stackblitz. thats what you should need.

Comment: alright. to be clear. if i select any date and save it in local storage. how to read and show same saved value in datepicker input field.

Comment: hey thanks for your time man.. i fix it .. its just silly cache issue in browser..

Comment: can you pls tell me how to integrate this [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/revqynyravm?file=app%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.html) with mine. i want user to give their input at any acceptable format in input field and same want show in view

Comment: not sure what you're trying to do. but you can use angular datepipe to display the date in any format. like {{ yourDate | date: 'dd/mm/yy' } you can put any format instead of 'dd/mm/yy'.

Comment: check my stackblitz html. look at <h1> appEndDate at the end.

Comment: yeah thats fine .. i did that. what i want is . i want to allow user edit date manually as they want .ex: if user givs **02/Apr/2019** or **02-Apr-2019** in mat-input then this should be shown in my view without any changes if i print {{appEndDate }}

Comment: your updated stackblitz gives me **Your Date: 21 00 19** when i give `appEndDate = new Date('20Apr2019'); `

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe check this. I'm not sure how to do what you want. I would recommend to keep one format. you will make it more complicated than it needs to be. I changed the date format in stackblitz. just check how you can change the format change date: ' ' for your chosen format.